# Corrupted InnoDB table, mysqlcheck and mysqldump crash server

Tags: mysql, innodb, corruption

I manage a Percona XtraDB Cluster that uses a network storage with a flapping connection. Periodically we experience a high iowait with crashes and remount of the fs in read-only. Replacing the storage is, unfortunately, not an option for now.

Recently I noticed that when mysqldump or mysqlcheck are run, they crash the MySQL server on the node, with an error `mysqlcheck: Got error: 2013: Lost connection to MySQL server during query when executing 'CHECK TABLE ... '`

Here's the content of `mysqld.log` during the crash:

```
InnoDB: Error in pages 9479 and 9480 of index "PRIMARY" of table "foobar"."quux"
InnoDB: broken FIL_PAGE_NEXT or FIL_PAGE_PREV links
2015-09-28 14:39:45 7f015813b700 InnoDB: Page dump in ascii and hex (16384 bytes):

(...)

InnoDB: End of page dump
2015-09-28 14:39:45 7f015813b700 InnoDB: uncompressed page, stored checksum in field1 4038097986, calculated checksums for field1: crc32 2787032309, innodb 4038097986, none 3735928559, stored checksum in field2 1190336748, calculated checksums for field2: crc32 2787032309, innodb 1190336748, none 3735928559, page LSN 4 3652646491, low 4 bytes of LSN at page end 3652646491, page number (if stored to page already) 9479, space id (if created with >= MySQL-4.1.1 and stored already) 18
InnoDB: Page may be an index page where index id is 67
InnoDB: (index "PRIMARY" of table "foobar"."quux")
2015-09-28 14:39:45 7f015813b700 InnoDB: Page dump in ascii and hex (16384 bytes):

(...) 

InnoDB: End of page dump
2015-09-28 14:39:46 7f015813b700 InnoDB: uncompressed page, stored checksum in field1 554678569, calculated checksums for field1: crc32 2178598661, innodb 554678569, none 3735928559, stored checksum in field2 1065260512, calculated checksums for field2: crc32 2178598661, innodb 1065260512, none 3735928559, page LSN 10 202985777, low 4 bytes of LSN at page end 202985777, page number (if stored to page already) 6792, space id (if created with >= MySQL-4.1.1 and stored already) 18
InnoDB: Page may be an index page where index id is 67
InnoDB: (index "PRIMARY" of table "foobar"."quux")
InnoDB: Corruption of an index tree: table "foobar"."quux", index "PRIMARY",
InnoDB: father ptr page no 55234, child page no 9479
PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 14; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 30; hex 34616434393538322d353232372d653863302d326466662d353461663639; asc 4ad49582-5227-e8c0-2dff-54af69; (total 36 bytes);
 1: len 6; hex 000000000dd7; asc       ;;
 2: len 7; hex c8000001741ea1; asc     t  ;;
 3: len 5; hex 99951259cb; asc    Y ;;
 4: len 5; hex 99951259cb; asc    Y ;;
 5: len 30; hex 62633965323864352d383865382d343466322d393337322d353339303931; asc bc9e28d5-88e8-44f2-9372-539091; (total 36 bytes);
 6: len 30; hex 62633965323864352d383865382d343466322d393337322d353339303931; asc bc9e28d5-88e8-44f2-9372-539091; (total 36 bytes);
 7: len 1; hex 80; asc  ;;
 8: len 30; hex 64356664666538352d656431652d346465362d383363612d616439663164; asc d5fdfe85-ed1e-4de6-83ca-ad9f1d; (total 36 bytes);
 9: len 8; hex 436f6e7461637473; asc Contacts;;
 10: len 4; hex 6c696e6b; asc link;;
 11: len 30; hex 7b226f626a656374223a7b226e616d65223a224d72204a6f7264616e204e; asc {"object":{"name":"Mr John Hacker; (total 343 bytes);
 12: len 4; hex 80000000; asc     ;;
 13: len 30; hex 7b226e616d65223a22222c22646f635f6f776e6572223a22222c22757365; asc {"name":"","doc_owner":"","use; (total 72 bytes);
 n_owned: 0; heap_no: 2; next rec: 751
PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 2; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 30; hex 34616435616262302d303535662d333939612d613038652d353439396461; asc 4ad5abb0-055f-399a-a08e-5499da; (total 36 bytes);
 1: len 4; hex 0000d7c2; asc     ;;
 n_owned: 0; heap_no: 277; next rec: 4688
InnoDB: You should dump + drop + reimport the table to fix the
InnoDB: corruption. If the crash happens at the database startup, see
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html about
InnoDB: forcing recovery. Then dump + drop + reimport.
2015-09-28 14:39:46 7f015813b700  InnoDB: Assertion failure in thread 139643749381888 in file btr0btr.cc line 1492
InnoDB: We intentionally generate a memory trap.
InnoDB: Submit a detailed bug report to http://bugs.mysql.com.
InnoDB: If you get repeated assertion failures or crashes, even
InnoDB: immediately after the mysqld startup, there may be
InnoDB: corruption in the InnoDB tablespace. Please refer to
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: about forcing recovery.
12:39:46 UTC - mysqld got signal 6 ;
This could be because you hit a bug. It is also possible that this binary
or one of the libraries it was linked against is corrupt, improperly built,
or misconfigured. This error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.
We will try our best to scrape up some info that will hopefully help
diagnose the problem, but since we have already crashed, 
something is definitely wrong and this may fail.
Please help us make Percona XtraDB Cluster better by reporting any
bugs at https://bugs.launchpad.net/percona-xtradb-cluster

key_buffer_size=25165824
read_buffer_size=131072
max_used_connections=7
max_threads=202
thread_count=10
connection_count=5
It is possible that mysqld could use up to 
key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_threads = 105204 K  bytes of memory
Hope that's ok; if not, decrease some variables in the equation.

Thread pointer: 0xf4de780
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
stack_bottom = 7f015813ad38 thread_stack 0x40000
/usr/sbin/mysqld(my_print_stacktrace+0x35)[0x8fa965]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(handle_fatal_signal+0x4b4)[0x665644]
/lib64/libpthread.so.0(+0xf710)[0x7f0185a25710]
/lib64/libc.so.6(gsignal+0x35)[0x7f0183e6b625]
/lib64/libc.so.6(abort+0x175)[0x7f0183e6ce05]
/usr/sbin/mysqld[0xa10d84]
/usr/sbin/mysqld[0xa16cc8]
/usr/sbin/mysqld[0x917920]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_ZN7handler8ha_checkEP3THDP15st_ha_check_opt+0x6a)[0x5a422a]
/usr/sbin/mysqld[0x835fc3]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_ZN19Sql_cmd_check_table7executeEP3THD+0xc2)[0x836cd2]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z21mysql_execute_commandP3THD+0x33d5)[0x6ed235]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z11mysql_parseP3THDPcjP12Parser_state+0x658)[0x6f0958]
/usr/sbin/mysqld[0x6f0acd]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z16dispatch_command19enum_server_commandP3THDPcj+0x19d5)[0x6f2de5]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z10do_commandP3THD+0x22b)[0x6f42cb]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z24do_handle_one_connectionP3THD+0x17f)[0x6bc52f]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(handle_one_connection+0x47)[0x6bc717]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(pfs_spawn_thread+0x12a)[0xaf611a]
/lib64/libpthread.so.0(+0x79d1)[0x7f0185a1d9d1]
/lib64/libc.so.6(clone+0x6d)[0x7f0183f218fd]

Trying to get some variables.
Some pointers may be invalid and cause the dump to abort.
Query (7efebc091d30): is an invalid pointer
Connection ID (thread ID): 2336
Status: NOT_KILLED
```

It is clear that the table `foobar.quux` is badly damaged. The application using the database still works (although with reduced performances), and so do `SELECT` statements.

The mysqlcheck tool cannot be used to fix it, so the solution I'm aware of is to do a `SELECT * FROM quux INTO OUTFILE`, drop the table, and do a `LOAD DATA INFILE` during the next maintenance window. Are there drawbacks with this way of proceeding, and are there other options to fix the table?

**EDIT:** I've restarted the MySQL server with increasing values of `innodb_force_recovery` from 1 to 4, and the result is always the same:

- mysqldump fails with an error `mysqldump: Error 2013: Lost connection to MySQL server during query when dumping table quux at row: 156915`
- a MySQL command `SELECT * FROM quux INTO OUTFILE '/root/quux.sql';` fails shortly after with an error `ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server during query`

Shall I try `innodb_force_recovery=5` and `innodb_force_recovery=6`? What could be the drawbacks?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`mysqlcheck` won't fix corruption in InnoDB table. You need to dump data from the table and re-create it.

Start MySQL with `innodb_force_recovery` option. Try values from 1 to 6 until MySQL starts.

Dump the table with `mysqldump`.

Drop the table.

Restart MySQL w/o `innodb_force_recovery`.

Reload the dump.

Comment: MySQL starts normally even with the default value `innodb_force_recovery=0`. One should not play with this setting as values of `innodb_force_recovery` equal to 4 or greater are considered dangerous (see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html). Does setting this value higher than 0 guarantee that mysqldump will run without crashing the MySQL server?

Comment: It's on (`innodb_file_per_table=1`).

Comment: Then take `quux.ibd`, upload it on https://recovery.twindb.com . If it manages to recover and shows valid records, extract the records from the ibd file with tool https://github.com/twindb/undrop-for-innodb . Then DROP the table and reload it from the dump to tool generates.

Comment: The table contains sensitive data, I'm not allowed to send it to an unknown online service. Besides, the files is more than 1Gb in size.

Comment: I'm sure twindb does an excellent service, and to be honest I'd be happy to upload the data to see if they can repair it. However giving the database to external people is not an option unless they sign a NDA. It's not me who makes the rules. The table got corrupted after a malfunction of the storage system, by the way. What do you mean by step #2?

Comment: It's perfectly fine that you can't upload the ibd file. By step #2 I mean "extract the records from the ibd file with tool github.com/twindb/undrop-for-innodb". Particularly, you need to follow scenario described in https://twindb.com/recover-corrupt-mysql-database/

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I've tried undrop-for-innodb but it seems unable to recover the table, as `dumps/default/quux` contains only: 
`-- Page id: 3, Format: COMPACT, Records list: Valid, Expected records: (0 0)` `-- Page id: 3, Found records: 0, Lost records: NO, Leaf page: YES` Any other suggestion to recover the data?

Comment: Just one empty page? It doesn't look correct. Are you sure you specify right index_id?

Comment: Yes, the index_id is correct.

Comment: For at least 15 days the database is corrupt and degraded! Why don't you just hire experts to fix it ? If you don't like twindb call Percona. This problem is a no brainier

Comment: The answer "Hire someone to do it" to a question "How do I do X?" on SE is hardly useful. By the way, this is a development environment.

Answer (score 8):

For what it's worth, I've found that `mysqlcheck -o` can effectively repair corrupted InnoDB tables since it in fact does a "*recreate + analyze*". I had a corrupt table that was preventing mysql from starting. First I tried:

```
mysqlcheck -r db_name table_name
```

Which returns:

> ```
> db_name.table_name
> note     : The storage engine for the table doesn't support repair
> ```

Then I tried:

```
mysqlcheck -o db_name table_name
```

And voilà...

> ```
> db_name.table_name
> note     : Table does not support optimize, doing recreate + analyze instead
> status   : OK
> ```

Not sure this would repair every kind of corruption but it worked for me.

Comment: mysqlcheck -r db_name table_name fixed it for me

Answer (score -2):

I have been dealing with innodb corruption.

i thought i would try a few things before dumping and reimporting the databases.

the check all database was not working for me, but this did.
i used the command below and didn't specify a table name.

I believe this checks/repairs every table in the database which could be very lengthy depending on your number of tables, but overall did the trick and things are back up and running.

```
mysqlcheck -o db_name
```

NOTE: login to to mysql and run show databases;

to get a list of your databases and then insert the name in the above command and then let it run for a few.

I was having issues with nextcloud and it fixed them for me.